# Modulo angle (rotation) in $2D$ space

Tags: geometry

Input parameters:
space dividor (number), vector (vec2)

Desired result:
Divide space in $X$ sectors, then move all vectors to one sector. (Angle of any vector wont be larger then $360/X$.)

Example of behavior that I made but seems to long:

- First, calculate $360$/space dividor which results in angle that we use as modulo.
- Lets say we have space divider $6$, so $360/6 = 60$
- Then calculate angle of the given vector.
- Lets say the result is $173$°
- Do modulo$(173, 60) = 53$
- Now create new unit vector with $53$°
- Calculate length of given vector
- Result is unit vector multiplied by length.

My question is, is there any shorter way to achieve same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah...that's pretty much what you have to do. The function you're building is discontinuous (at the boundary of each "wedge", so you implicitly need cases, which the "modulo" is providing. To do that, you need the angle to use in the modulo.

A small alternative: you could call your angle  $\alpha = 360/n$ and build the matrix 
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha   & -\sin \alpha
\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If you write your vectors as column vectors, then you can compute 
$$
Mv, M^2 v, M^3 v, \ldots
$$
until you end up with a vector that's within your 'wedge'. But this is, for anything except the smallest value of $n$, a pretty slow solution compared to conversion to the length-angle form, division, and conversion back.